# RXTX java CL/RL trouble

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

How can i set the terminal attributes over RXTX lib in java. Like as: stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600 min 0 time 3  -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel  -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke